# How to parse through complex season and episode formatting in Python Pandas

Tags: python, regex, parsing, pandas, unicode

I'm trying to clean up some data and am struggling to do so in Python/Pandas.  I have a series of data with TV Show Titles.  I would like to do the following:

1. check if there are integers at the end of the string
2. if there is only one integer, return everything before that part of the string
3. if there are multiple parts of the string that are integers, return the first all of the string and then the 1st integer

So here is my inputs:

```
Brooklyn 99 103
Hit The Floor 110
```

Outputs:

```
Brooklyn 99
Hit The Floor
```

As a separate function (or functions), I would like to remove any additional season/ episode formatting and any strings after it :

Inputs

```
Hot in Cleveland s6 ep03
Mutt & Stuff #111
LHH ATL 08/31a HD
LHH ATL 04/04 Check
Esther With Hot Chicks Ep. 1
Suspect 2/24
Suspect 2/24 HD
```

Output

```
Hot in Cleveland
Mutt & Stuff
LHH ATL
LHH ATL
Esther With Hot Chicks
Suspect
Suspect
```

I've written a function like so:

```
def digit(value):
    return value.isdigit()


def another(value):
    li = value.split(" ")
    x = len(filter(digit, value))
    ind = li.index( str(filter(digit, li)[0]) ) 
    try: 
        if x > 1:
            return " ".join(li[:ind+1])
        else: 
            value.str.replace(r'(\D+).*', r'\1').str.replace(r'\s+.$', '').str.strip()
    except:
        return value.str.replace(r'(\D+).*', r'\1').str.replace(r'\s+.$', '').str.strip()

data["LongTitleAdjusted"] = data["Long Title"].apply(another)
data["LongTitleAdjusted"]
```

but I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-3526b96a8f5a> in <module>()
     15         return value.str.replace(r'(\D+).*',      r'\1').str.replace(r'\s+.$', '').str.strip()
     16 
--->     17 data["LongTitleAdjusted"] = data["Long Title"].apply(another)
         18 data["LongTitleAdjusted"]

C:\Users\lehmank\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-     packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args,   **kwds)
   2167             values = lib.map_infer(values, lib.Timestamp)
   2168 
-> 2169         mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2170         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
   2171             from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:62578)()

<ipython-input-49-3526b96a8f5a> in another(value)
     13             value.str.replace(r'(\D+).*',    r'\1').str.replace(r'\s+.$', '').str.strip()
     14     except:
---> 15         return value.str.replace(r'(\D+).*',    r'\1').str.replace(r'\s+.$', '').str.strip()
     16 
      17 data["LongTitleAdjusted"] = data["Long Title"].apply(another)

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'str'
```

for regex

Comment: Please include the full traceback. It tells you (and us) where the error is occurring.

Comment: Thank you for the help @skrrgwasme

Comment: Are you  using pandas just to filter the data?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham correct I am using pandas to filter the data to get the number of integers in the string value

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick with your sample data set:

```
df['title'].str.replace(r'(\D+).*', r'\1').str.replace(r'\s+.$', '').str.strip()
```

but it would also convert `Brooklyn 99` to `Brooklyn`

Comment: Hi Max, is there a way to check if there is more than one int at the end of the formatting and preserve the first?

Comment: @KateLehman, i've just added `regex` tag to your question - hopefully some  RegEx experts can solve it

Comment: what I'm thinking is I could do something like an if statement that checks if there is more than one int in the string and then just returns the strings before it and then use your regex as the else...

Comment: i figured out a function to solve the problem I mentioned above, but I am getting an error on regex AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'str' Do you know how to fix this?